# How do apps like zillow serve up data?

Tags: shapefile, geodjango, spatial-query, large-datasets

I'm a total newbie to GIS, but attempting to build an app similar to zillows that quickly serves up data based on user input.

Currently, i'm collecting the data via shp files which are being store in a postgis database, and then standardized and serialized into json. When standardized, there will be thousands of shapefiles for the user to query upon.

Based on intuition alone, this feels 'heavy'. Is this a standard/decent way to handle the backend or no?

-using geoDjango for server side framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off delivering  MVT TILES OR PBF as geobuff. Highly optimized and read by mapbox GL JS  or leaflet via plugins.

- [ST_AsMVT](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html) will only show the points, lines and polygons not attributes.
- Use [ST_AsGeoJSON](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) to create a centroid for polygons for labels.

Answer (score 0):

They use more structurally and light weight data, rather than shp files. 
In these situations data is collected by users themselves, using front end spatial lib i.e openlayers or leaflet. Then drawn objects (land or ...) by using server side framework save in spatial db i.e postgresql. In
Spatial db, there is a standard field named {geom} that contains wkb encoding with a srid (coordinate system).
Geo django supports most simple and complex spatial query and topological relationships. It's a good choice if you want to handle spatial data for property management or real estate services.